# XSLT - accessing a query string parameter

Tags: .net, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'm new to XSLT so hope someone can help out :)

We have access to a jobs feed: https://www.myjobscotland.gov.uk/edinburghhotjobs/

I use .net to check if the query string is null or empty then set the visibility of panels to show either jobs.xsl or singlejob.xsl.

.

**If the query string is empty the following jobs.xsl is pulled through:**

index.aspx

```
<abc:XsltParser runat="server" ID="jobs" XSLTransformFileLocation="~/assets/jobs.xslt"  InputXmlFileLocation="https://www.myjobscotland.gov.uk/edinburghhotjobs/" />
```

.

jobs.xslt

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="jobs/job">
         <xsl:sort select="PublishEndDate" order="ascending" />
         <!-- Order by closing date -->
         <xsl:if test="InternalOrExternal = 'External'">
            <!-- Only show external jobs -->
            <div class="job">
               <div class="job-title">
                  <h4>
                     <a href="index.aspx?refnum={UniquePortalID}" title="View job details for '{PositionTitle}'">
                        <xsl:value-of select="PositionTitle" />
                     </a>
                  </h4>
               </div>
               <div class="job-refno">
                  Ref No.:
                  <xsl:value-of select="UniquePortalID" />
               </div>
               <div class="job-salary">
                  Salary: £
                  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(SalaryFrom, &quot;###,###.00&quot;)" />
                  - £
                  <xsl:value-of select="format-number(SalaryTo, &quot;###,###.00&quot;)" />
               </div>
               <div class="job-hours">
                  Hours:
                  <xsl:value-of select="HoursPerWeek" />
                  -
                  <xsl:value-of select="PositionType" />
               </div>
               <div class="job-closing">
                  Closing Date:
                  <xsl:value-of select="PublishEndDate" />
               </div>
            </div>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

My jobs.xsl file loops through all the jobs and displays key information on the page ie job title, salary, closing date etc.

The idea is that the user can click on the job title and they will be presented with the full job details.

```
<a href="index.aspx?refnum={UniquePortalID}" title="View job details for '{PositionTitle}'"><xsl:value-of select="PositionTitle"/></a>
```

.

**If the query string contains a value then singlejob.xsl is pulled through:**

index.aspx?refnum=abc123

```
<abc:XsltParser runat="server" ID="jobs2" XSLTransformFileLocation="~/assets/singlejob.xslt"  InputXmlFileLocation="https://www.myjobscotland.gov.uk/edinburghhotjobs/" />
```

This XSLT will display the full job description:

singlejob.xsl

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" version="1.0">
   <xsl:output method="html" />
   <xsl:template match="/">
      <xsl:for-each select="jobs/job">
         <xsl:sort select="PublishEndDate" order="ascending" />
         <!-- Order by closing date -->
         <xsl:if test="InternalOrExternal = 'External'">
            <!-- Only show external jobs -->
            <div class="job-detail">
               <div class="job-title">
                  <h3>
                     <xsl:value-of select="PositionTitle" />
                  </h3>
               </div>
               <br />
               <xsl:value-of select="description1" disable-output-escaping="yes" />
            </div>
         </xsl:if>
      </xsl:for-each>
   </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

.

The problem is, i don't know how to get singlejob.xslt to display only the job the user selected, it currently prints out all jobs :(

Is there any way i can access the query string in singlejob.xslt? Something like

```
<xsl:if test="UniquePortalID = Querystring.value['refnum']">
```

Or

Can I pass then access the questring value?

```
XSLTransformFileLocation="~/assets/singlejob.xslt?refnum=abc123"
```

.

How do I do this?

Sorry it's quite a long post.

thanks